# Pari GP - Checking if user keyed in a prime number

Tags: primes, pari, pari-gp

I am currently learning how to use Pari GP and right now i am trying to write out a code on checking whether if the user did key in a prime number or not.

Here is my code.

```
printf("\t%s \n","PrimeNo(P): To check if it is a prime or not");

PrimeNo(p)={

if(isprime(p)||1, print("Prime numbers only"));

if(isprime(p)||0, print("Prime numbers stored"));

print(p);

}
```

Problem is my first "if" line works by identifying that it was not a prime, but when i key in a prime number, both line appeared.

Would appreciate if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statements have two tests each, so both are true if `p` is prime (the first if isprime(p) OR 1, the second if isprime(p) OR 0).  I think you want something like:

```
PrimeNo(p) = { if( isprime(p), print("Yep"), print("Nope") ); print(p); }
```

Here we're using the if-then-else form of Pari/GP's if, so we do the first item if isprime(p) is true and the second item if it is false.  This also has the advantage of only calling `isprime` once, which is important if your numbers are large (one can also debate `ispseudoprime` vs. `isprime` but there is no difference for 64-bit inputs).

Comment: @JamesQuek You can also write `PrimeNo(p) = { print(if(isprime(p), "Yep", "Nope")); print(p) }` if you prefer. Everything in PARI is a function, including `if`.